# Can't get Getters from SoundCloud HTML5 Widget API

Tags: html, widget, soundcloud

I'm struggeling with the Soundcloud HTML5 Widget API. The Methods and Events are working fine, but i can't log the getters. I've been looking around in the Soundcloud API documentation but i can't find the problem. The Soundcloud Playground is working fine, but the examples they give in their blog http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api, arent. So i'm wondering, am i missing something here, or is there something wrong with the API? This is my stripped HTML, wich is not working:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('sc-widget'));
            widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, ready());

            function ready() {
                widget.getDuration(function(durationSC) {
                    console.log('Duration: ' + durationSC);
                });
            }

            $('button').click(function() {
                widget.toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="sc-widget" src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/39804767&show_artwork=false&liking=false&sharing=false&auto_play=false" height="195" scrolling="no" width="480" frameborder="no"></iframe>
<button>Play / Pause</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are invoking `ready()` instead of passing it as a callback – `widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, ready);`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. There is indeed a problem with the API right now – a quick fix will be to use `https` in the widget's iframe `src`.

We'll try to deploy the fix as soon as possible and fix the documentation to point at `https` which should be used.